# What is the technology behind BitTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, cdn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Bittorrent work?](https://superuser.com/questions/245390/how-does-bittorrent-work)

What is the [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29) protocol, and the technology behind it? What is the difference between BitTorrent and a [content distribution network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (CDN)?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for this forum - please read the FAQ.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(protocol)

Comment: A question regarding the BitTorrent protocol perhaps is better answered in the WebApps forum? If your question is about a specific BitTorrent app, please clarify to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

Well,

- [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28software%29) (the software) uses the - BitTorrent protocol.
- What is the difference between "BitTorrent" and CDN? One is a technology, the other is an organizational approach. A CDN is not a technology to start with - it is a network used to deliver content using whatever standard the customer needs (**mostly** HTTP) using technology. The *term* CDN does not imply any specific technology.

Comment: In a ven diagram, CDN would be a large circle, and BitTorrent would be a smaller circle completely within the CDN circle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you're looking for, but if you find the wiki site lacking for [bitorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29) and [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)'s maybe you can specify what you're trying to figure out?